# Angular 2, Webpack Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor... is not defined when add an external lib

Tags: angular, webpack, jplayer

When I add a library (in my case it is `jplayer`) I got error

> external "vendor_d73928c…":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: vendor_d73928c989153b363873 is not defined

at line 
`module.exports = vendor_d73928c989153b363873` in file `webpack:///external "vendor_d73928c989153b363873"`

Here is my code (which add vendor `jplayer`).

```
entry: {
    vendor: [
        'bootstrap',
        'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
        'style-loader',
        'jquery',
        '@angular/common',
        '@angular/compiler',
        '@angular/core',
        '@angular/http',
        '@angular/platform-browser',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
        '@angular/router',
        '@angular/platform-server',
        'angular2-google-maps/core',
        'jplayer'
    ]
},
```

Do I missing something?

Comment: `jplayer/dist/**/*.+(js|css|html|gif|png|swf)`  is this helpful?

Comment: No it not work, it return error when I run `webpack` in cmd
> ERROR in dll vendor
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jplayer/dist/**/*.+(js|css|html|gif|png|swf)' in F:\code\KOAIT\Makanikai\LanaiNew\Lanai
 @ dll vendor

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the solution. Just exit visual studio, run
 `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`
 `webpack` 
in cmd, in the project folder. After that, open visual studio again

Comment: Thanks bro u saved me